# Как оптимизировать картинки на сайте wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, оптимизация

Есть сайт, который на pagespeed имеет параметр оптимизации 49/100 главной страницы, это очень мало, хотелось бы выйти хотя бы из красной зоны.

Для этого, понятное дело, нужно исправить хотя бы важные ошибки, это:

Оптимизировать изображения. Поставил плагин WP Smush, он как бы оптимизировал все изображения в медиафайлах, но осталась проблема, например в портфолио, там выводятся не миниатюры изображений, а родные уменьшенные картинки, а pagespeed хочет чтоб я их урезал, если я это сделаю, то и в самом портфолио внутри будет маленькая картинка, аналогичная ситуация и с блоком "последнее в блоге", тут же выводятся последние записи с блога, но картинки выводятся не в миниатюрах, а в родных картинках вставленных в статью и уменьшенных для показа в этом блоке, надеюсь Вы поняли, что я имел ввиду.

Что делать со скриптами и css, блокирующим отображение в верхней части страницы? Ставил плагины типа: autoptimize или speed boost pack, или тот же W3 Total Cache и после включения некоторых параметров я получал + на pagespeed, но страница могла потерять слайдер или развалится вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт **портфолио** - вам надо создать кастомный размер изображения, соответствующий реальному размеру портфолио 266x250, прогнать картинки через regenerate thumbnails и выводить картинку уже кастомного размера.

**Сократите время до получения первого байта от сервера** - смените хостинг, лучше на VPS. Как минимум, попробуйте поставить объектное кеширование с Redis.

**Устраните ресурсы, блокирующие отображение** - я не знаю, что это за чудесные скрипты типа `/s/45665f.js`. Выглядят вообще подозрительно. Откажитесь от них или запускайте их после события DOMContentLoaded. css для NotoSans надо запускать inline, тогда swap сработает как надо. Но я не вижу, используется этот шрифт или нет. Может, отказаться от него? У вас и так много шрифтов.

**Используйте современные форматы изображений** - ставьте ewww plugin, и выводите всё в webp.

**Удалите неиспользуемый код CSS** - практически нерешаемо, слишком много ручной работы.

**Настройте подходящий размер изображений** - тут понятно, выводите изображения подходящего размера.

**Минимизируйте работу в основном потоке** -уменьшайте кол-во скриптов на странице

**Сократите размер структуры DOM** - упрощайте структуру страницы и кол-во элементов на ней